# Product rating table form rewrite

Tags: magento2, ratings

I want to write a function in module file in `app/code/[vendor_name]/[module_name]/...` This function will use **object manager** only and is to show current product rating table to let customers rate the product.

> Attention: Not get rating summary! No `xml` codes! No `phtml` codes!
>   No `$block` used!

Answer (score 0):

You will get product rating summary from below code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');

$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
```

Comment: Not get rating summary!

Comment: Have you set product in  it?

Comment: Product set as ID. Need get product rating form not rating history

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this it will work in phtml file :**

```
<?php
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $oldId = isset($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : "";
    $productId = 5;
    $data['id'] = $productId;
    $block->getRequest()->setParams($data);
    echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Review\Block\Form')->toHtml();
    if($oldId) {
        $data['id'] = $oldId;
        $this->getRequest()->setParams($data);
    }
```

Comment: No $block used. You are not qualified.